# Using a state machine to handle calls to action for a user to complete a profile in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state

I'm developing a way for a user to gradually complete their profile, a bit like LinkedIn and others do.  Depending on where they are in completing their information they'll be asked one of the following:

- Sign up to a run
- Add a goal
- Add an avatar
- Thanked for completing their profile

Having given it some thought, I think I'll approach this using the [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem.

I've got as far as adding the following to the `user` model:

```
state_machine :profile_state, :initial => :needs_to_sign_up_to_a_run, :namespace => 'profile' do
  event :signed_up_for_run do
    transition :needs_to_sign_up_to_a_run => :needs_goal
  end

  event :completed_goal do
    transition :needs_goal => :needs_avatar
  end

  event :provided_avatar do
    transition :needs_avatar => :complete
  end

  state :needs_to_sign_up_to_a_run
  state :needs_goal
  state :needs_avatar
  state :complete
end
```

However, I'm not sure that this is the best way to define the `events` or `transitions`.

Given the user can complete the goal/avatar/signup in multiple ways (i.e. from their user edit page, from a right hand panel, as part of the signup flow).  So, in practice they could provide an avatar prior to a goal, and therefore the `completed_goal` isn't right.

Perhaps I could use some sort of validation to determine the state?
Maybe a state machine is completely the wrong approach.

I'd love any advice on approaching this design problem.

Comment: On the right path, naming is one of those things even experienced programmers find difficult.

Comment: So you think a state machine is the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

I would say state_machine is not good choice here.

I would recommend [wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked), Step-by-step wizard controller.

[here is a screen cast on it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked)

Comment: I've used Wicked elsewhere in the app, specifically for when a user transitions to becoming a full member.  Do you know whether I can use Wicked to handle a partial on the page, rather than the whole controller/action?

Comment: even you can use wicked partially. or use another separate controller  for that.

Answer (score 1):

Going on the above, I decided to use Wicked.  I implemented it as follows:

```
class CallsToActionController < Wicked::WizardController

  layout false

  steps :sign_up_to_run, :add_goal, :add_avatar, :thank

  def show
    @user = current_user
    case step
    when :sign_up_to_run    
      skip_step if @user.attendances.intended.size > 0
    when :add_goal    
      skip_step if @user.goals.count > 0
    when :add_avatar    
      skip_step unless @user.avatar.file.nil?
    end
    render_wizard
  end

  def update
    @user = current_user
    render_wizard
  end

end
```

This allowed me to have a series of partials in `app/views/calls_to_action` such as `add_goal`:

```
<div id="goalForm">
  <% @goal = current_user.goals.new %>
  <%= render :partial => 'goals/form' %>
</div>
```

I then handled submission through a standard controller:

```
class GoalsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @goal = current_user.goals.new(params[:goal])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @goal.save
        format.js
      else
        format.js { render 'reload' }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

To tie it all together, as I wanted the wizard to sit in a div within the page, the javascript create action looked like this:

```
$("#call-to-action-response").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'goals/success') %>");
$("#call-to-action").load("<%= pre_member_calls_to_action_url(:sign_up_to_run) %>").hide().fadeIn('slow');
```

Hopefully that's useful for someone attempting something similar!